# In C++, how do I remove the lowest element from an array and later use the updated array to compute sum and average of all numbers inside the array?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

**The main goal of the program is to identify the lowest number inside the array(which is size 10 or list[10] inside the declarations), get the sum of all 10 numbers, remove the lowest number and get the average of the 9 remaining elements inside the array.** Inside the code, I have already identified the lowest number inside the array. I tried to assign min to 0 which clearly did not work and got stuck after that.

Watched many youtube videos and searched this up online, but many videos and tutorials only offer to remove the lowest number with the array given by the programmer and not by user input (cin>>). Help would be much appreciated by a beginner computer science student, thank you!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>  
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int dim = 10;
    int list[dim];
    int i;
    int min = list[0];
    int sum = 0;
    int ave;
    int temp;

    cout << "enter number: " << endl; // takes input
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
    {
        cout << "loc[" << i << "] ";
        cin >> list[i];
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < dim; i++) // gets the lowest num
    {
        if (list[i] < min)
        {
            min = list[i];
        }
    }

    cout << "lowest numb is: " << min << endl; // displays the lowest num
    min = 0; // tries to replace the element from the list[] array with the value of 0

    cout << "sum is: " << sum << endl;

    ave = sum / 9; // tries to compute the average of 9 numbers, without the lowest element in the array
    cout << "average is: " << ave << endl;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain the logic of `if (list[i] < max) { min = list[i]; }`? I guess you got a type there. You also initialize `min` and `max` to `list[0]`, but what will be the value of `list[0]` at this moment? You are reading the data only later. Maybe you should fix those bugs before moving on.

Comment: Are you forced to use a c style array here? Typically we use std::vector or std::list or some other container type if we need to add and remove elements in runtime.

Comment: Are you coming from Python? I'm asking because I feel like your code has similarities with Python which might not work in C++ the way you expect it to work.

Comment: the if(list[i] < max) { min = list[i]; } reads all the elements in the array and compares it with each other. the lowest element gets left out and will be saved in the min variable. 

i am also forced to use a c style array here.

Comment: @SeanMabuti Why would the smallest element end up in `min`? if we assume the other bug I mentioned is fixed and `min` and `max` both have the vlaue of `list[0]` and think about input 3, 1, 2. So 1st iteration: `min = max = 3, list[i] = 1` => `1 < max = true` => `min = 1`. 2nd iteration: `min = 1, max = 3, list[i] = 2` => `2 < max = true` => `min = 2`. So 2 is the smallest element here? you should compare against `min`, not `max`.

Comment: the bug max was something that I used earlier to show the highest number element in the array. the variable max was assigned to 0, which is the same as the value of min. fixed the code and updated it above

Answer (score 1):

I want to show how using standard libraries help to get the things much easier, even if it is harder to read for a novice programmer. But knowing STL makes a lot things easier. And using "modern" for loops and lambdas makes the live much easier. I was forced to write it, as I got the impression the code can be written a bit more "modern" :-)

```
int main()
{
    constexpr int dim = 10;

    // we use set as container as it sorts internally its elements which
    // makes it very easy to get lowest element simply on pos 0.
    std::set<int> values;

    for(int i = 0; i<dim; i++)
    {   
        int v;
        std::cout<<"loc["<<i<<"] ";
        std::cin>>v;
        values.insert( v );
    }   

    // identify the lowest number
    // as std::set is sorted, simply print the first element in the set we see lowest number
    std::cout << "Lowest Number is " << *values.begin() << std::endl;

    // get the sum of all 10 numbers
    // as we later on need to calculate the sum again, create a functor which we can reuse on the fly
    auto sumFunc = [&values]() { int sum = 0; for ( auto el: values ) { sum+= el; } return sum;};

    std::cout << "Sum of all elements " << sumFunc() << std::endl;

    // remove the lowest number
    // as we know the lowest element is at the first position, simply remove begin()
    values.erase( values.begin() );

    // get the average of the 9 remaining elements
    // again take sum and divide by number of elements
    // as we expect that average is not really an int, we convert to double
    std::cout << "Average of remaining elements " << static_cast<double>(sumFunc()) / values.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You are unnecessarily use `set` and `erase`, doing the sum 2 times, do not use `accumulate`  and input validation. But, all the fancy stuff is not needed at all. You can already and immedialtely calculate the sum and the min value directly while reading the values from `cin`, so in the input loop. Then, subtract the min value from the sum and divide by always (dim-1). Anyway. a very good solution +1

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proper solution written with modern C++ features:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>


int main( )
{
    constexpr std::size_t initialSizeOfArray { 10 };
    std::vector<int> numbers( initialSizeOfArray );

    std::cout << "Enter " << initialSizeOfArray << " numbers:" << '\n';

    for ( std::size_t idx { }; idx < initialSizeOfArray; ++idx )
    {
        std::cout << "loc[" << idx << "] : ";
        std::cin >> numbers[ idx ];
    }

    int min { numbers[ 0 ] };
    std::size_t idxOfMin { };

    for ( auto it = numbers.cbegin( ); it != numbers.cend( ); ++it )
    {
        if ( *it < min )
        {
            min = *it;
            idxOfMin = std::distance( numbers.cbegin( ), it );
        }
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << "The lowest number is: " << min << '\n';

    numbers.erase( numbers.cbegin( ) + idxOfMin );

    int sum { };

    for ( const auto& num : numbers )
    {
        sum += num;
    }

    std::cout << "The sum is: " << sum << '\n';

    double avg { static_cast<double>( sum ) / static_cast<double>( numbers.size( ) ) };
    std::cout << "The average is: " << avg << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Use a `std::vector` and its `erase` member function to remove an element from any position in the vector.

Sample input/output:

```
Enter 10 numbers:
loc[0] : 10
loc[1] : 9
loc[2] : 8
loc[3] : 7
loc[4] : 6
loc[5] : 5
loc[6] : 4
loc[7] : 3
loc[8] : 2
loc[9] : 1

The lowest number is: 1
The sum is: 54
The average is: 6
```

Comment: BTW: You tell us "modern". It feels very old style as you use "old fashioned" for loops, have code duplication,  do all and everything "hand crafted". OK, to explain simple algorithms it is perfect to hand craft min/sum/average, but the very old style loops are not "modern". And you should create a function for calc the sum. Code duplicates are really a bad thing... even for novice programmers!

Comment: @Klaus That's valid. But honestly, I wanted to keep the OP's own format and only improve it to make it safer. I don't want to teach him how to structure his code in a good manner just by writing an answer to his question. Let's keep it simple and digestible.

Comment: "Let's keep it simple" yes, it is absolute ok. But I stumble on your statement "modern" :-)

Comment: @Klaus What I meant by saying **modern** is C++ with iterators, range-based and iterator-based for loops, C++ style casts, etc.  As you can already see, the OP has not used any of these in his/her code.

Comment: My personal idea of "modern" means post C++03 style... Your first given solution was fully C++03 conform which is "old style c++". My understanding of your idea of modern seems to be use C++ features in general. But hey, it is quibbling :-)

Comment: Yeah, I might have a wrong definition of **modern** C++ in my mind. Modern C++ generally means post C++11. For me, any C++ code that looks similar to C or uses C features like raw arrays and pointers, C standard IO, malloc, etc. is **unmodern** C++.

Comment: The last is not c++, even not modern or old fashioned, it is simply c-style.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to understand, why your code does not work.

I will explain this to you and then add some comments.

First the major problems:

- Arrays in c++ need to have a compile time size. You must change your first statement to: `const int dim = 10;` or better to
- You initialize you your min variable to early. At this point in time, you did not yet read list[0]. So, please move this statement to after the first loop.
- You do not calculate a sum at all. So please add as a last statement in the first loop: `sum += list[i];`
- There is no need to really erase something. You can just subtract the min value from the sum. Then you have the sum, without the min value. So, please add after the second loop the statement: `sum -= min;`
- The type of the variable ave should be double

There are some additional recommendations

- Delete unused variables. If you want to know which variables are unused, then enable all warnings in your compiler.
- You should not use `using namespace std;` but better, fully qualified names. But, as a beginner, you may continue to do.
- Normally you should do input validation. Users may enter abc, instead of a number. Then your program will not work correctly.

You working program with the above modifications could be:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    constexpr int dim = 10;
    int list[dim];

    int sum = 0;
    double ave;

    cout << "enter number: " << endl; // takes input
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
    {
        cout << "loc[" << i << "] ";
        cin >> list[i];
        sum += list[i];
    }
    int min = list[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < dim; i++) // gets the lowest num
    {
        if (list[i] < min)
        {
            min = list[i];
        }
    }
    sum -= min;

    cout << "lowest numb is: " << min << endl; // displays the lowest num
    min = 0; // tries to replace the element from the list[] array with the value of 0

    cout << "sum is: " << sum << endl;

    ave = sum / 9.0; // tries to compute the average of 9 numbers, without the lowest element in the array
    cout << "average is: " << ave << endl;
}
```